# WSO2 EI Connector for Neo4j Graph database

Tags: neo4j, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Is there a connector in WSO2 to integrate with Neo4j Graph database?
The Connector should provide an ability to execute CQL statements and run basic operations, such as create, update, delete, and select nodes against a Neo4j Graph database instance.

The objective here is to expose REST API using dataservice in WSO2 EI by entering CQL for Neo4j Graph database similar to RDBMS datasource (Ex: MYSQL, Oracle..etc) where we enter SQL instead.

If we have to build a Custom Connector, any suggestions on the approach will be helpful.